# Is there a way to call a function when a SwiftUI Picker selection changes?

Tags: swift, onchange, swiftui, picker

I would like to call a function when selectedOption's value changes. Is there a way to do this in SwiftUI similar to when editing a TextField?

Specifically, I would like to save the selected option when the user changes the selectedOption.

Here is my picker:

```
struct BuilderPicker: View {
    let name: String
    let options: Array<String>
    @State var selectedOption = 0
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(name)
                .font(.body)
                .padding(.leading, 10)
            Picker(selection: $selectedOption, label: Text(name)) {
                ForEach(0 ..< options.count) {
                    Text(self.options[$0]).tag($0)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                .padding(.trailing, 25)
        }.onTapGesture {
            self.selectedOption = self.selectedOption == 0 ? 1 : 0
        }
            .padding(.init(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 0))
            .border(Color.secondary, width: 3)
            .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 15, bottom: 0, trailing: 15))
            .font(.body)
    }

}
```

I’m still new to SwiftUI and would love some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If the @State value will be used in a View, you don't need extra variable `name`

```
  struct BuilderPicker: View {
// let name: String = ""
 let options: Array<String> = ["1", "2","3","4","5"]
 @State var selectedOption = 0
 var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Text(options[selectedOption])
            .font(.body)
            .padding(.leading, 10)
        Picker(selection: $selectedOption, label:    Text(options[selectedOption])) {
            ForEach(0 ..< options.count) {
                Text(self.options[$0]).tag($0)
            }
        }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            .padding(.trailing, 25)}
//        }.onTapGesture {
//            self.selectedOption = self.selectedOption == 0 ? 1 : 0
//        }
        .padding(.init(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 0))
        .border(Color.secondary, width: 3)
        .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 15, bottom: 0, trailing: 15))
        .font(.body)
    }


 }
```

If you need separated operation on the @State, the simplest way is adding one line : onReceive() to the view.

```
  HStack {
        Text("")
            .font(.body)
            .padding(.leading, 10)
        Picker(selection: $selectedOption, label: Text("")) {
            ForEach(0 ..< options.count) {
                Text(self.options[$0]).tag($0)
            }
        }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            .padding(.trailing, 25)}
  //        }.onTapGesture {
 //            self.selectedOption = self.selectedOption == 0 ? 1 : 0
 //        }
        .padding(.init(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 0))
        .border(Color.secondary, width: 3)
        .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 15, bottom: 0, trailing: 15))
        .font(.body)
        .onReceive([self.selectedOption].publisher.first()) { (value) in
            print(value)
    }
```

Comment: the reason didSet isn't working for you is because you commented out the onTapGesture. I'm trying your idea now.

Comment: Don't use extra gesture if everything on @State var is built in.

Comment: This works, but it feels like there should be a better way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: This works, but "[self.selectedOption].publisher.first()" w00t ?:)

Comment: Is `[self.selectedOption].publisher.first()` Public API? It doesn't feel like Public API, but gosh darnit it works.

Comment: You can use ‘Just(self.selectedOption)’

Comment: What is purpose of brackets in '[self.selectedOption]'?

Comment: The purpose of the brackets is to put selectedOption into an Array.  Once in an array, then you can call publisher on it as it conforms to Sequence protocol.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much @E.Coms -- using .onReceive(Just(...)) {value in } is fantastically useful! I'm finally able to run code in a child view when a variable passed from its parent changes.

Comment: It's possible to enter an infinite loop with this if you update an ObservedObject in the callback.  You'll know really quick as it will lock the ui and your memory will spike.

Comment: Can confirm that this is a dangerous approach if you update an ObservedObject in the callback.

Comment: Best answer. onReceive() is the key.

Answer (score 6):

The previous solution will end up in an infinite loop if you update an `ObservedObject` in the callback since `.onReceive` is also called when the View got rendered.

→ A better approach is to use a `.onChange` method on the Binding itself:

```
Picker(selection: $selectedOption.onChange(doSomething), label: Text("Hello world")) {
        // ...
    }
```

To do so you need to write an `extension` for `Binding` like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60130311/3917662).

Comment: You're definitely correct about the loop. However, rather than use an extension on Binding, you can just use the .onChange(of: perform:) modifier on the Picker itself, where of: is your @State variable and perform: is the action you want to perform.