# In SwiftUI, how do I know when a Picker selection was changed? Why doesn't didSet work?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, picker

I have a `Picker` in a SwiftUI `Form`, and I'm trying to process the value whenever the picker changes. I expected to be able to do this with `didSet` on a variable that represents the currently selected value.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    enum TransmissionType: Int {
        case automatic
        case manual
    }

    @State private var selectedTransmissionType: Int = TransmissionType.automatic.rawValue {
        didSet {
            print("selection changed to \(selectedTransmissionType)")
        }
    }

    private let transmissionTypes: [String] = ["Automatic", "Manual"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedTransmissionType,
                           label: Text("Transmission Type")) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< transmissionTypes.count) {
                            Text(self.transmissionTypes[$0])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Picker` UI works (mostly) as expected: I can see the default value is selected, tap into the picker, it opens a new view, I can select the other value, and then it goes back to the main form and shows me the new value is selected. However, `didSet` is never called.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58676483/is-there-a-way-to-call-a-function-when-a-swiftui-picker-selection-changes), but it seems odd to me to add more to my `View` code instead of just processing the new value when the variable changes, if that is even possible. Is it better to use `onReceive` even though it results in a more complicated view? My main question is: **What's wrong with my code to prevent `didSet` from being called?**

I used [this example](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-a-picker-and-read-values-from-it) to get to this point.

Beyond my regular question, I have a few others about this example:

**A)** It seems weird how I have an `enum` and also an `Array` to represent the same two values. Can someone also suggest a better way to structure it to avoid this redundancy? I considered a `TransmissionType` object, but that seemed like overkill compared to an `enum`... maybe it's not?

**B)** When tapping into the picker, the screen with the picker options slides over, and then the two options jump up a bit. This feels jarring and jumpy and a bad user experience. Am I doing something wrong here that's causing the bad UX? Or is it probably a SwiftUI bug? I'm getting this error every time I change the picker:

`[TableView] Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to load and perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view bounds, trait collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and will also cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout passes. Make a symbolic breakpoint at UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy to catch this in the debugger and see what caused this to occur, so you can avoid this action altogether if possible, or defer it until the table view has been added to a window.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I started typing this out earlier, and returned to find LuLuGaGa had beaten me to the punch. :D But since I have this anyway...

**Main question:** From the [Swift Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID215):

> "When you assign a default value to a stored property, or set its
>   initial value within an initializer, the value of that property is set
>   directly, without calling any property observers."

So the property observer will not fire when the view is constructed. But when a `@State` variable changes, a new instance of the view is constructed (remember, views are structs, or value types). Thus, the `didSet` property observer is, practically speaking, not useful on `@State` properties.

What you want to do is create a class that conforms to `ObservableObject`, and reference it from your view with the `@ObservedObject` property wrapper. Because the class exists outside the struct, you can set property observers on its properties, and they will fire like you're expecting.

**Question A:** You can use just the enum if you make it conform to `CaseIterable` (see example below)

**Question B:** This appears to be a SwiftUI bug, as it happens with any `Picker` inside of a `NavigationView`/`Form` combo, as far as I can tell. I'd recommend [reporting it to Apple](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com).

Here is how I would remove the redundancy of the enum and array, and save the selection in UserDefaults:

```
extension ContentView {
    // CaseIterable lets us use .allCases property in ForEach
    enum TransmissionType: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
        case automatic
        case manual

        // This lets us omit 'id' parameter in ForEach
        var id: TransmissionType {
            self
        }

        // This just capitalizes the first letter for prettier printing
        var description: String {
            rawValue.prefix(1).uppercased() + rawValue.dropFirst()
        }
    }

    class SelectionModel: ObservableObject {
        // Save selected type to UserDefaults on change
        @Published var selectedTransmissionType: TransmissionType {
            didSet {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedTransmissionType.rawValue, forKey: "TransmissionType")
            }
        }

        // Load selected type from UserDefaults on initialization
        init() {
            if let rawValue = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "TransmissionType") {
                if let transmissionType = TransmissionType(rawValue: rawValue) {
                    self.selectedTransmissionType = transmissionType
                    return
                }
            }
            // Couldn't load from UserDefaults
            self.selectedTransmissionType = .automatic
        }
    }
}
```

Then your view just looks like

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = SelectionModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker(selection: $model.selectedTransmissionType, label: Text("Transmission Type")) {
                        ForEach(TransmissionType.allCases) { type in
                            Text(type.description)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect explanation 

Answer (score 6):

There are two problems here.

1) the jumping can be solved if title style is ".inline".

2) OnReceive() is one of the simplest way to replace the `didSet` request with a combine framework method, which is the core tech of SwiftUI.

```
struct ContentView: View {



enum TransmissionType: Int {
    case automatic
    case manual
}

 @State private var selectedTransmissionType: Int =   TransmissionType.automatic.rawValue {
    didSet {
        print("selection changed to \(selectedTransmissionType)")
    }
}

private let transmissionTypes: [String] = ["Automatic", "Manual"]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section {
                Picker(selection: $selectedTransmissionType,
                       label: Text("Transmission Type")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< transmissionTypes.count) {
                        Text(self.transmissionTypes[$0])
                    }
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline) // this solves jumping and all warnings.
    }.onReceive(Just(selectedTransmissionType)) { value in
    print(value) // Just one step can monitor the @state value.
    }
   }


}
```

Comment: I like this use of Combine to read the change in `@State` variables. +1 Unfortunately, although the large vertical jump doesn't occur with `displayMode: .inline`, there is still horizontal jittering when you first open the `Picker`, so it's still a bug that needs reporting.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `.inline` but I have a large title on the main navigation view, and it is still buggy when I make this one .inline` unless I also set that one to `.inline`. Seems like it must be bugs in SwiftUI

Answer (score 3):

didSet doesn't get called on @State because it is a wrapper - you are setting a value within the state not the state itself. The he important question is why would you want to know that it was set?

Your view can be simplified a bit:

If you declare your enum as having raw type of String, you don't need your Array of names. If f you declare it as CaseIterable you will be able to get all cases by calling Array(TransmissionType.allCases). If it is declared as Identifiable as well you will be able to pass all cases straight into ForEach. Next you need to pass the rawValue into the text and remember to place the tag on it so that the selection can be made:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    enum TransmissionType: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {

        case automatic
        case manual

        var id: String {
            return self.rawValue
        }
    }

    @State private var selectedTransmissionType = TransmissionType.automatic

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedTransmissionType,
                           label: Text("Transmission Type")) {
                            ForEach(Array(TransmissionType.allCases)) {
                                Text($0.rawValue).tag($0)
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't see where the weird jumping comes from - have you replicated it on device as well?

Comment: Thanks! The reason I want to know when the value changes is so I can save it in a UserDefault to save between app launches. Also, yes, the jumping happens on device.

Comment: In that case you have yo use ObjectBinding not a State as this is a not variable local to the view

Answer (score 1):

Hey did not read the whole thing but if you want to know what the changed value of the picker is. Just use .onChange(of: YourPicker) { changedValue in }